# ValueError: Invalid salt in flask

Tags: flask, bcrypt, flask-login

I am still in learning phase and having this issue while going through tutorials
I do not understand why I am getting this error `ValueError: Invalid salt`

Complete Error Code is:

> File "C:\Users\Aparichit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
> File "C:\Users\Aparichit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()
> File "C:\Users\Aparichit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1499, in dispatch_request
> return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
> File "C:\Users\Aparichit\Desktop\NoViewsIndia\noViews\views.py", line 46, in login_page
> if attempted_user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(attempted_user.password_hash,
> attempted_password):
> File "C:\Users\Aparichit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_bcrypt.py",
> line 193, in check_password_hash
> return safe_str_cmp(bcrypt.hashpw(password, pw_hash), pw_hash)
> File "C:\Users\Aparichit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\bcrypt_*init*_.py",
> line 105, in hashpw
> raise ValueError("Invalid salt")

My `model.py` code is:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    userName = db.Column(db.String(15), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self.password

    @password.setter
    def password(self, plain_text_password):
        self.password_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plain_text_password).decode('utf-8')
```

And `views.py` is

```
@app.route('/admin_login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_page():
    login_form =Login()
    if login_form.validate_on_submit():
        attempted_password = login_form.pWord.data
        attempted_user = User.query.filter_by(userName = login_form.uName.data).first()
        print(f'Route Username is {login_form.uName.data}')
        print(f'Route User is {attempted_user}')
        print(f' Route Password is {attempted_password}')
        print(f'Route Hashed Password is {attempted_user.password_hash}')
        if attempted_user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(attempted_user.password_hash, attempted_password):
            login_user(attempted_user)
            flash(f'You have successfully logged in, {attempted_user.name}')
        else:
            flash('Invalid Username and Password')
    return render_template('admin_login.html', loginForm=login_form)
```

And `form.py` is

```
class Login(FlaskForm):
    uName = StringField(label='User Name')
    pWord = PasswordField(label='Password')
    submit = SubmitField(label='Login')
```

And password that are saved:
[Hassed Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRKfK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode your data before storing the data

```
pw_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(‘hunter2’).decode(‘utf-8’)
```

[read the docs](https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage)

Comment: In `setter property` inside `module.py`, I already applied it. Do I need to do it anywhere else?

 @password.setter
    def password(self, plain_text_password):
        self.password_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plain_text_password).decode('utf-8')

Comment: try deleting all the passwords and entering new once ,